# how to show show db. data for all template using base template

Tags: html, django, model, jinja2

hello I m new in Django I m creating a Django ecommerce project nd I  created I slider in base template I want to show slider in all the template ..first template its working properly but if I go for some other template like section then its not showing images nd product name  which I extends from base template ..hope some one help us .

**base.html**

```
<div class="container bg">
        <div id="demo" class="carousel slide my-3" data-ride="carousel">
            <ul class="carousel-indicators">
                <li data-target="#demo" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
                <li data-target="#demo" data-slide-to="1"></li>
                <li data-target="#demo" data-slide-to="2"></li>


            </ul>

            <div class=" carousel-inner ">
                <div class="carousel-item active">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-xs-3 col-sm-3 col-md-3">
                            <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
                                <img src="/media/{{cake.0.images}}" class="card-img-top" alt="...">
                                <div class="card-body">
                                    <h5 class="card-title">{{cake.0.prodname|title}}</h5>
                                    <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
                                    <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-xs-3 col-sm-3 col-md-3">
                            <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
                                <img src="/media/{{cake.1.images}}" class="card-img-top" alt="...">
                                <div class="card-body">
                                    <h5 class="card-title">{{cake.1.prodname|title}}</h5>
                                    <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
                                    <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-xs-3 col-sm-3 col-md-3">
                            <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
                                <img src="/media/{{ic.0.images}}" class="card-img-top" alt="...">
                                <div class="card-body">
                                    <h5 class="card-title">{{ic.0.prodname|title}}</h5>
                                    <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
                                    <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-xs-3 col-sm-3 col-md-3">
                            <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
                                <img src="/media/{{ic.1.images}}" class="card-img-top" alt="...">
                                <div class="card-body">
                                    <h5 class="card-title">{{ic.1.prodname|title}}</h5>
                                    <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
                                    <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="carousel-item">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-xs-3 col-sm-3 col-md-3">
                            <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
                                <img src="/media/{{pb.0.images}}" class="card-img-top" alt="...">
                                <div class="card-body">
                                    <h5 class="card-title">{{pb.0.prodname|title}}</h5>
                                    <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
                                    <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>





                        <div class="col-xs-3 col-sm-3 col-md-3">
                            <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
                                <img src="/media/{{pb.1.images}}" class="card-img-top" alt="...">
                                <div class="card-body">
                                    <h5 class="card-title">{{pb.1.prodname|title}}</h5>
                                    <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
                                    <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-xs-3 col-sm-3 col-md-3">
                            <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
                                <img src="/media/{{bs.0.images}}" class="card-img-top" alt="...">
                                <div class="card-body">
                                    <h5 class="card-title">{{bs.0.prodname|title}}</h5>
                                    <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
                                    <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-xs-3 col-sm-3 col-md-3">
                            <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
                                <img src="/media/{{bs.1.images}}" class="card-img-top" alt="...">
                                <div class="card-body">
                                    <h5 class="card-title">{{bs.1.prodname|title}}</h5>
                                    <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
                                    <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>


                <div class="carousel-item">

                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-xs-3 col-sm-3 col-md-3">
                            <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
                                <img src="/media/{{sauth.0.images}}" class="card-img-top" alt="...">
                                <div class="card-body">
                                    <h5 class="card-title">{{sauth.0.prodname|title}}</h5>
                                    <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
                                    <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-xs-3 col-sm-3 col-md-3">
                            <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
                                <img src="/media/{{ind.0.images}}" class="card-img-top" alt="...">
                                <div class="card-body">
                                    <h5 class="card-title">{{ind.0.prodname|title}}</h5>
                                    <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
                                    <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-xs-3 col-sm-3 col-md-3">
                            <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
                                <img src="/media/{{inter.0.images}}" class="card-img-top" alt="...">
                                <div class="card-body">
                                    <h5 class="card-title">{{inter.0.prodname|title}}</h5>
                                    <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
                                    <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-xs-3 col-sm-3 col-md-3">
                            <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
                                <img src="/media/{{gj.0.images}}" class="card-img-top" alt="...">
                                <div class="card-body">
                                    <h5 class="card-title">{{gj.0.prodname|title}}</h5>
                                    <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
                                    <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

that my base template where I define my db. data like images and product name
**bengalisweet.html**

```
<!doctype html> {%extends "myproj/base.html" %} {% block title_block %}bengali sweet {%endblock%}{%load static %} {% block body_block %}
<div id="product">
    <div class="hd">
        <h1>Best Bengali Sweet Listed Here</h1>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="container" xmlns:data="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <div id="demo" class="carousel slide my-3" data-ride="carousel">'
        <ul class="carousel-indicators">
            <li data-target="#demo" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
            {% for i in range %}
            <li data-target="#demo" data-slide-to="{{i}}"></li>
            {% endfor %}
        </ul>

        <!--        slideshow starts here-->

        <div class="carousel-inner">
            <div class="carousel-item active">

                <div class="col-xs-3 col-sm-3 col-md-3">
                    <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
                        <img src='/media/{{product.0.images}}' class="card-img-top" alt="...">
                        <div class="card-body">
                            <h5 class="card-title">{{product.0.prodname|title}}</h5>
                            <p class="card-price">{{product.0.price}}</p>
                            <p class="card-text">{{product.0.desc|truncatewords:10|title|linebreaks}}</p>
                            <div class="btn2">
                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Order Now</button>
                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger cart">Add to Cart</button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                {% for i in product|slice:"1:" %}
                <div class="col-xs-3 col-sm-3 col-md-3">
                    <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
                        <img src='/media/{{i.images}}' class="card-img-top" alt="...">
                        <div class="card-body">
                            <h5 class="card-title">{{i.prodname|title}}</h5>
                            <p class="card-price">{{i.price}}</p>
                            <p class="card-text">{{i.desc|truncatewords:10|title|linebreaks}}</p>
                            <div class="btn2">
                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Order Now</button>
                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger cart">Add to Cart</button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                {% if forloop.counter|divisibleby:3 and forloop.counter > 0 and not forloop.last %}
            </div>
            <div class="carousel-item">
                {% endif%} {% endfor %}
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>

    <a class="carousel-control-prev " href="#demo" role="button" data-slide="prev">
        <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
    </a>
    <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#demo" role="button" data-slide="next">
        <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
    </a>
    {%endblock%}
```

that is my child template I want to show my slider for all the existing templates

Answer (score 0):

make sure you passed the data alongside the html template in all the views and not just the base.html view

```
data = SomeModel.objects.all()
context = {"data":data}
return render(request, 'example.html', context)
```

Comment: yes bro its working in home ..but not even other page

Comment: can you send your views code?